# Jquery: simple way to detach and re-atttach an element?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation, detach

I know about detach() and the varios methods to insert html. But how do you detach an element, leave a placeholder, and then replace that placeholder with the element later on?

The only solution I can think of is to check for a prev(), then next(), then parent(). Store that placeholder, and then later on use that placeholder to put the element back.

There has to be a simpler way...

Thanks.

Comment: There is a simpler way, it's called `hide()`

Comment: It depends on the specific situation you are in. In some cases it makes sense to just store the collection of all elements in the list in a variable so that you can later append them all in the original order, other times it makes more sense to maintain an array with the desired order so that you can always select the original "prev" or "next" element that is still in the list, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method is what you need, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Use good 'ol `$(elem).css('visibility', 'hidden');` to hide it while keeping it's place,

and then `$(elem).replaceWith(newElem);` to swap it out;

Answer (score 0):

For attaching an element you must use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) like this

```
 $('form').append("<div id='appended'>Hello World</div>");
```

For detaching an element you should use [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) like this

```
 $('#appended').remove();
```

Comment: Problem arises when you want to keep the position inside its parent